# Rails: has_many Active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm wondering how you would simulate a :has_many :through using an AR call.

Ultimately, I'm trying to find the subcategories that belong to a site, not the top level categories, which is what the query currently gives me.

Models:

```
class Categories < AR
  :has_many :subcategories, :through => :cat_subcat_links
  :has_many :cat_subcat_links
end
```

Linking Model:

```
class CatSubcatLinks < AR
  :category_id
  :subcategory_id
  :site_id
end
```

At the moment, if I want to get which categories belong to a particular site I perform:

```
Category.joins(:cat_subcat_links).where(:cat_subcat_links => {:site_id => 1})
```

The query that returns:

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `cat_sub_links` ON `cat_sub_links`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` WHERE `cat_sub_links`.`site_id` = 1
```

The problem is

```
`cat_sub_links`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
```

I need it to say

```
`cat_sub_links`.`subcategory_id` = `categories`.`id`
```

That will cause the query to return me the subcategories. Thoughts?

Thanks in advanced,

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I had to write the join instead since I can't specify a :source like I normally would if I created the relationship.

```
Category.joins("JOIN cat_sub_links ON cat_sub_links.subcategory_id=categories.id").where(: cat_sub_links => {:site_id => @site_ids})
```

I'll leave the answer out for a few days if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have in your site.rb

```
class Site < AR
  has_many :cat_subcat_links
  has_many :subcategories, :through => :cat_subcat_links
  has_many :categories, :through => :cat_subcat_links
end
```

Couldn't you just do:

```
Site.find([your_site_id]).categories
```

Also:

```
Site.find([your_site_id]).subcategories
```

Also just a thought; are you sure it wouldn't be better to use [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree)  or [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) instead?

Comment: Thanks Luke, your answer would be right, but in my specific case I cannot create the relationship.